# BPy Create an Empty object without lost the selections before it (Blender v2.70)

Tags: python, objects, selection-tools

i have again tiny problem :(

is it possible in blender python to create an **Empty** object without lost the selections before it ?

I have selected some objects and when i create an **Empty** object, I lose the previously set selection.

ㅤ

I hope there's a solution for that.

best regards -DevilSam

Comment: I'd try to save the prior selection in my own list, and then after adding an object, restore it from there.

Comment: own list ? do you mean a object group ?...

Comment: No, just adding something like
old_selection = []
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects: old_selection.append(obj)
#create empty
for obj in old_selection: obj.select = True

Comment: You're welcome. And right after the object creation you can deselect it, or deselect all before restoring the selection with bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='TOGGLE')